# how to make Designable UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, ibdesignable

I am a beginner. I want to make a swift file that contains a code to make Designable UIImage, so I will not edit the UI element display by coding, just in Interface builder by assigning this swift file to UI class.

I can do something similar in UIButton, for example if i want to make round corner and add border to UIButton i can do something like this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DesignableButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadiusOfButton : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadiusOfButton
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            layer.borderColor = uiColor.cgColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else { return nil }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }


}
```

for UIImage, usually we want to add round corner or to make circular UIImage by using this code

```
// round corner
        someImage.layer.cornerRadius = checkinPhoto.bounds.width/20
        someImage.clipsToBounds = true

 //  circular image
        someImage.layer.cornerRadius = someImage.frame.size.width / 2
        someImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

how to make those code to @IBDesignable code class for UIImage like Designable UIButton above? I have tried to make by subclassing UIImage, but i don't why i can't access  `layer` and `clipToBounds`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `UIImage` as designable because `UIImage` is not a `UIView` subclass you need to make designable your `UIImageView` instead, the `UIImage` can't be rendered by itself needs a `UIImageView` to be rendered

**Use this class**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundableImageView: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0.0{
        didSet{
            self.applyCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor : UIColor = UIColor.clear{
        didSet{
            self.applyCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth : Double = 0{
        didSet{
            self.applyCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var circular : Bool = false{
        didSet{
            self.applyCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    func applyCornerRadius()
    {
        if(self.circular) {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height/2
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true
            self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(self.borderWidth)
        }else {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true
            self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(self.borderWidth)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.applyCornerRadius()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        applyCornerRadius()
    }

}
```

Comment: how about the circular image, could you please add that functionality to the code, sir ?